# How to decrypt password wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I forgot my wordpress password, but i get encrypted the password like this:

`$P$BFEJX322HwG.qdSF58yLSTA90vjrRQ.`

What is the best way to decrypt my wordpress password?

Comment: That is probably a hash, not an encrypted password.

Comment: you cant, but you can reset your password

Comment: if you know any other password and its encrypted form, then replace its encryption and use the password of that site and after login, you can change it easily.

Answer (score 0):

The password is not encrypted (two-way) but hashed. Therefore, it is not possible to get back the initial value. More about this topic on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Google would help you in this case: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-reset-a-wordpress-password-from-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress simply go to database and look for table named *_users may vary with the prefix set by you look for user that you want to reset the password then click on the edit in front of that perticular row go to password column and type your new password and select MD5 in dropdown front of password field and then save.

Comment: Don't use MD5 it's a unsafe hash method

Comment: MD5 is the encryption used by Wordpress for user password and the question is how to reset the password

Comment: there are other ways,a quick Google shows this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/update-from-md5-to-sha256/

Comment: sorry to say but you are trying to sell something else  for question simple solution is that i provide he dose not want to change the encryption type he simply want to reset the lost password that's it.

Comment: Just like when people use old versions of PHP and mysql, you need to say that it's unsafe and not good method.

Answer (score 0):

Well wordpress hash are actually **salted hash** which is hard to crack.
There are many **python scripts to crack WordPress hash,** but the problem is those scripts seems useless.
Because you have to crack it using **wordlist.**
I mean using that python script it'll check one by one password.
It took years so it is useless.
I can't say it's impossible, but it's hard to crack.

Answer (score -1):

Go to
localhost/phpmyadmin -> your site database -> table named "something_users" -> edit

change the password and select md5

Done.

Comment: Don't use MD5 it's a unsafe hash method

Comment: @Andreas what methods do wordpress support?

Comment: @Vishwa don't know, but that is unrelated. Don't use it either way. There are always ways around it.

Comment: okay, assume we use sha1. is it better? and what are the ways around it?

Comment: @Vishwa yes, Sha is a better encryption.

Comment: what would be the best method as of 2019? which can successfully use with wordpress? can we use sha1 with wp?

Comment: I always use md5 . @Andreas as you said I will dig into it.

Comment: To my knowledge WordPress uses md5 by default https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password but can be overwritten in your theme/plugin etc to use other methods.

For the purpose of this question though the password will need to be reset and hashed using whichever method is currently in use (probably md5)